# Flask 404 Errors After Adding SSL

Tags: flask, ssl

I've got a Flask App on AWS Lightsail.   The webhooks and requests were working as intended, but when I added SSL certs, it now has 404 errors for all routes.

The request looks like this...

```
url = "http://api-dev.xyz.io:8000/webhook"
data = {'foo' : 'bar'}
headers = {'content-type' : 'application/json'}
r = requests.post(url, json=data, headers=headers)
```

The error log says...
`"[33mPOST /webhook HTTP/1.1[0m" 404 -`

The app looks like this...

```
import toml
import datetime

Config = toml.load("config.toml")

app = Flask(__name__)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    context = (Config["SSLInfo"]["ssl_cert"], Config["SSLInfo"]["ssl_key"])
    app.run(debug=True, ssl_context=context, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)

    

@app.route("/webhook", methods=["POST"])
def webhook():
    if request.method == "POST":
        print("Data received from Webhook is: ", request.json)
        return "Webhook received!"
```

Answer (score 0):

The `app`.`run` needed to be moved to the end of the file below where the routes were declared.   It needed to look like this.

```
import toml
import datetime

Config = toml.load("config.toml")

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/webhook", methods=["POST"])
def webhook():
    if request.method == "POST":
        print("Data received from Webhook is: ", request.json)
        return "Webhook received!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    context = (Config["SSLInfo"]["ssl_cert"], Config["SSLInfo"]["ssl_key"])
    app.run(debug=True, ssl_context=context, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
```